# extract track changes information (inserted deleted text) from docx file

Tags: ms-word

I'm looking to extract the inserted and deleted text from a word document after it's been reviewed. I've been able to extract the comments using the following macro:

```
Sub ExportComment()
Dim s As String
Dim cmt As Word.Comment
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim workBk As Word.Document
Set workBk = ActiveDocument
Set doc = Documents.Add(Visible:=True)
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = doc.Range(0, 0)
Dim myTable As Table
Set myTable = doc.Tables.Add(Range:=myRange, NumRows:=workBk.Comments.Count, NumColumns:=6)
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each cmt In workBk.Comments
myTable.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = cmt.Index
myTable.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = cmt.Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
myTable.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text = cmt.Initial
myTable.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text = cmt.Scope
myTable.Cell(i, 5).Range.Text = cmt.Range.Text
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

But can't seem to figure out how to also get the inserted and deleted text from the tracked changes. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you used the `Comments` collection in your sample code, you will want to use the `Revisions` Collection (for example, `Dim rev as Word.Revision`). Unlike `Comments`, `Revisions` has a Type property that you can use to identify different varieties of Track Changes. Here are some revision types:

[image]

If you want to see example VBA code that extracts revisions, go to

http://www.thedoctools.com/downloads/basTrackChanges_Extract.shtml

which is referenced on the below page while discussing the issue of extracting revisions:

http://www.thedoctools.com/index.php?show=mt_trackchanges_extract