# how to combine changes tracked from several documents

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

For my application, there is one document (Microsoft word), and this document is reviewed by several people in the "Track changes" mode, so the input to my application is the original document and the reviewed documents with changes (like insert/delete/comments).

By this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128246/extract-track-changes-information-inserted-deleted-text-from-docx-file/11131122#11131122), I know how to extract all the changes from the reviewed documents.

I want to combine all the changes from all the reviewed documents into ONE document, and make all the changes "accepted", so the output of my application is one modified Microsoft document with all the changes (delete/insert/comment) accepted.

My problem is that I don't know how to combine the changes from several documents into one single document.

Comment: You have some code - please share it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> what i want is to combine all the changes from all the reviewed
>   documents into ONE document, and make all the changes "accepted"

I'm not sure if Word provides this functionality out-of-the-box.

You might consider using something like the [diff algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm) to align the changes between documents one-by-one and apply them.

Comment: Hello, Philip, thank you very much for your reply. I just found the MS Word has this function ( go to "Review" tab, click "Compare", then choose "Combine", then add the source document and revised one one by one). By this way the multiple documents with revisions can be combined. But I am looking for a way to do this by VB code..